# schedule black berry application

Tags: java, blackberry, notifications, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I have created a BlackBerry application,
HelloBlackBerry extends UiApplication and it renders the fields and
screen layout stuff.
And I have a class called Notification and it does some notifications.
What I wanted to do is call that Notification class every 1 hour. Like schedule.
But how can I do that, I tried schedule api but no luck,
if anybody can give me a hand,
thanks

Comment: Do you want to run your application once per hour, or assuming it's running run a method in Notification once per hour?

Comment: I just want to run the Notification class once per hour, so it does a random notification every hour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you implement [RealtimeClockListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RealtimeClockListener.html) in your Notification class. Register the listener with [Application.addRealtimeClockListener()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#addRealtimeClockListener%28net.rim.device.api.system.RealtimeClockListener%29). In clockUpdated test the time to see if the hour has passed and if so run your notification.

Comment: How about you give it a try, and if it doesn`t work post your code?